# PHP function respondes differently to submit after preventDefault()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, submit, preventdefault

I'm using a PHP file (as part of a wordpress plugin), which contains several functions.
One of them builds an html form and another one deals with the submitted form.
I've added to the function that builds the form a `submit()` function in which I call an asynchronous function.
In order for it to finish before the form is submitted I'm using `preventDefault()` and a call to `submit()` when the async function finishes.
The problem is that my call to `submit()` after `preventDefault()` causes different results in the PHP function that handles the submitted form than the original submit.

Here's the PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit-reg']))
{
    $output = sreg_process_form($atts); 
    return $output;
}
else
{
    $data = array();
    $form = simplr_build_form($data, $atts);        
    return $form;               
}
```

When I don't use `preventDefault()` and `submit()` the condition is positive and the form is submitted normally.
When I do use them the second part is executed and the form is being rebuilt instead of submitted.
So the question is: what in `preventDefault()` and then `submit()` causes `isset($_POST['submit-reg']))` to be false and how can I fix it?
edit: Here's the JS:

```
$('#simplr-reg').submit(function(event)
{           
    event.preventDefault();
    codeAddress(function(success){}); //callback from googlemaps
});

function codeAddress(callback)
{               
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geoCodingStarted = true;

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status)
    {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
        {   
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            $("input[name=latitude]").val(latitude); 
            $("input[name=longitude]").val(longitude);      

            $('#simplr-reg').submit();          
        }                   
    });         
}  // end of code address
```

Comment: submit-reg is the name of the form?

Comment: You need to show the JS code as well, since that could be where the potential issue lies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you submit the form via normal methods then `submit-reg` is set. When you use preventDefaul() and send the form asynchronously then the value is never set, because the form is never submited, altough it's processed asynchronously. You should use another method to check is the form is being processed or built. Perhaps a hidden field. or another flag set dinamicaly on the page.

[From the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3)

> 17.13.3 Processing form data
>
> When the user submits a form (e.g., by
>   activating a [submit button](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#submit-button)), the user
>   agent processes it as follows.
>
> **Step one: Identify the [successful controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls)**
>
> **Step two: Build a form data set**
>
> A form data set is a sequence of
>   control-name/current-value pairs
>   constructed from successful controls
>
> **Step three: Encode the form data set**
>
> The form data set is then encoded
>   according to the content type
>   specified by the enctype attribute of
>   the FORM element.
>
> **Step four: Submit the encoded form**
>   **data set**
>
> Finally, the encoded data is sent to
>   the processing agent designated by the
>   action attribute using the protocol
>   specified by the method attribute.
>
> This specification does not specify
>   all valid submission methods or
>   content types that may be used with
>   forms. However, HTML 4 user agents
>   must support the established
>   conventions in the following cases:
>
> - If the method is `"get"` and the action
>     is an HTTP URI, the user agent takes
>     the value of action, appends a `?' to
>     it, then appends the form data set,
>     encoded using the
>     "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
>     content type. The user agent then
>     traverses the link to this URI. In
>     this scenario, form data are
>     restricted to ASCII codes.
> - If the method is `"post"` and the action is an
>     HTTP URI, the user agent conducts an
>     HTTP "post" transaction using the
>     value of the action attribute and a
>     message created according to the
>     content type specified by the enctype
>     attribute. For any other value of
>     action or method, behavior is
>     unspecified.
>
> User agents should render the response
>   from the HTTP "get" and "post"
>   transactions.

When you use `preventDefault()` you prevent this from happening making the variable ´submit-reg` unexistant because it is never set.

[More info from jQuery site](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

> Now when the form is submitted, the
>   message is alerted. This happens prior
>   to the actual submission, so we can
>   cancel the submit action by calling
>   .preventDefault() on the event object
>   or by returning false from our
>   handler.

Comment: @DarkThorne , so when I use `submit()` after `preventDefault()` the form isn't submitted?  Can't I set `isset($_POST['submit-reg']` as positive somehow?

Comment: @Ash `submit-reg` is automatically set when the form is submited. Now you can modify `simplr_build_form($data, $atts);` to create a hidden field with a value like `form-built` and then checking `isset($_POST['form-built']);` in the 'if () else` statement. Or you can rethink the js to take out the `preventDefault()`. There're a lot of ways to solve the problem, choose what suits you best!! :)

Answer (score 2):

If PHP's behaving differently, then its inputs are different. do `print_r($_POST)` in both situations and see what's different. PHP couldn't care less that you ran some Javascript on the page. All it'll see are some form values coming in.

If different values come in, then it'll behave differently. So check those inputs and figure out why your Javascript is changing the form data.

Comment: that makes sense. But my JS code doesn't change the value of 'submit-reg' which is the submit button. I need to understand why it gets different values on a regular submit and when calling `submit()` after `preventDefault()` .

Comment: Regardless, check what the server's receiving.

Comment: thanks a lot! using `print_r($_POST)` really exposed the problem.